# Fetch Sitecore Cache Details

Tags: caching, sitecore

I have a requirement that needs to fetch Caching Details which includes:

> > Analyze the current system caching which includes CDN setup, enabled HTML, data cache etc with invalidating of cache suggest.

I need to get Sitecore instance caching details in non Sitecore application like Windows Application.

> > What are the options to get Sitecore Instance Details in non Sitecore Application
> >
> > What all inputs i should provide to non Sitecore application to get Sitecore instance details.
> >
> > The non Sitecore application will be used as a tool which gets Sitecore application(Sitecore Instance) details like pipelines,workflows,caching etc.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Admin Tools**
Sitecore provides a basic cache monitoring page.
`/sitecore/admin/cache.asp`
and many other tools see `/sitecore/admin/`

**Performance counter**
You can use Windows Performance counters: see 
https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/sitecore-8-0-performance-counters/

On Azure application insight see https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/configure-application-insights-post-deployment.html

**Log file**
A lot of information is in the log file, http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Sitecore%20Fundamentals/Logging/  or Azure application insight https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/analytics.html

**Custom Admin page**
You can easily create your own admin page with the details you want to monitor. for the caching you can use the Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager in your code.

**Sitecore Event and Pipelines**
Sitecore is easy to extend with custom code, you can also easily add extra logging to you windows application. by subscribe to an Event https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/pipelines-and-events/events/  or add an extra process to a pipeline. http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/pipelines-and-events/pipelines/